# Is "long?" really a struct?

Tags: c#, nullable

By definition Nullable<> is a struct but when I call some generic function, it behaves like it's an object.

```
class GenController
{
    public void Get<T>(T id) where T : struct
    {
        Console.Write("is struct");
    }

    public void Get(object obj)
    {
        Console.Write("is object");
    }
}

long param1 = 1234;
new GenController().Get(param1);
// output is "is struct" as expected

long? param2 = 1234;
new GenController().Get(param2);
// output is "is object"
// obj seen at debug time as "object {long}"
// expected "is struct"
```

So the parameter is seen as an object instead of a struct.

Any idea of what's happening, am I misunderstanding the meaning of `struct`?

Is there a way to dispach `Nullable<T>` or `T` and `object` as different kind of parameters?

Comment: This question is a about overloads preference and not about nullables at all. See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZLxxQ), error should be telling.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters looks like Nullable is an exception for generic constraints

Comment: @jdweng - no, Nullable<T> is a struct, but a very special one.

Comment: @jdweng It's [very definitely a struct](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` is [definitely a struct](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).

Your question is more about the `where T : struct` generic type constraint, than it is about `Nullable<T>`.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

> **`where T : struct`**: The type argument must be a non-nullable value type.

`long?` is a *nullable* value type, and so isn't permitted by the `where T : struct` constraint.

Comment: so the nullable struct is passed via the object parameter, is it then boxed?

Comment: @TimRutter What do you mean by "the object parameter"? If you do `int? x = 3; object o = x` then the nullable int is boxed, yes. However, the runtime special-cases boxing with nullable value types, so that a nullable int is boxed as a normal int: you get the same result as if you did `object o = 3`. A `Nullable<T>` which has `HasValue = false`, e.g. `int? x = null`, gets boxed to a null reference, i.e. the same as `object o = null`.

Comment: i mean the second Get method which has an "object" parameter.  so it actually depends on whether the nullable has a value.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimRutter Then yes, you get the same effect as if you called `Get((object)1234)` (or `Get((object)null)` for a null nullable)

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question:

- `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`
- The `struct` constraint only allows not nullable structs.

---

With that said, you can specify that the parameter is nullable, like this:

```
public void Get<T>(T? id)
    where T: struct
{
    Console.Write("is nullable struct");
}
```

That would be one more overload to capture nullable structs.